# StackOverflowError while building my project

Tags: java, android, helios, stack-overflow, dex

Am using Eclipse 3.6.1 package and am developing an application for QR code generation, when i run the project it shows me an stack overflow error and prompting me to force close the workspace

```
    Unable to execute dex: java.lang.StackOverflowError. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
    Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.lang.StackOverflowError. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

I even modified my *eclipse.ini* but still the error remains

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
    -product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    1024m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
    -Xms512m
    -Xmx1024m
```

even deleted my .dex file and gave clean ,build and nothing worked out

some may say its because of the large java files in your build path, like the onBarcode.jar file which i am using for qr code generation

BUT IT IS NOT

because when executing my project in my laptop(os-opensuse,ram-3gb,eclipse-helios) showed the stack overflow error, the same project worked really very good and i rendered my QR code without any problem in my desktop(windows-vista,ram-1gb,eclipse-helios).

only difference between my laptop's eclipse workspace and my desktop eclipse workspace is the number of projects. my laptop has about - 20 projects in the project explorer as closed projects with one ready to run, but my desktop has only one project (ie) my current project

So is it a problem with eclipse IDE not able to manage between closed project memory leaving to a big stack overflow error???

how do i get cleared up with this error???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue using Eclipse 4.2 on windows 8.

I solved it by removing the Java 7 SDK, and installing the Java 6 SDK.
(I also downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse - not sure if that was necessary)